# Truncate line in C to continue on next line

Tags: c

I'm stuck on a program that I have to write.

Basically it asks the user for a character, and how many times they'd like that character displayed.  Only 10 characters per line.  I can't figure out how stop at 10 then continue on the next line.

Example output:

```
Enter a character: *
Enter the number of characters to display: 36
**********
**********
```

I'm currently using a For Loop.

EDIT**  My code

```
main () {
    int num = 0,i;
    char get_char;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &get_char);

    printf("Enter the number of characters to display: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);


    for (i = 0;i < num; i++) {
        printf("%.10c",get_char);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop works.  I'm afraid that my mind-reading satellite is current out-of-order so you'll need to show some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your current for loop after printing the character, add a condition:

```
 for (i = 0;i < num; i++) {
      printf("%c",get_char);
      if((i+1)%10==0) 
          printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You mean 10, not 9, i.e. i % 10 == 0 (after the i++, or i % 10 == 9, in front of the i++.) You can check for i % 10 != 0 after the for loop to put a nice tidy final newline at the end, when needed.

Comment: @JimFlood I edited according to OP's code now.

Comment: Looks good. I didn't notice the double i++ which you've fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't think of using modulus.

Answer (score 2):

To go to the next line, you will have to print out the `linefeed` character, which is indicated by using the escape sequence `\n` in C-style strings. When the compiler sees this sequence, it will use the linefeed character (whose hex value is `0a`). When the terminal sees this character, it moves the cursor to the next line.

To detect the end of a line, you could use either nested `for` loops or use the modulus (`%`) operator.

With nested `for` loops, you could simply keep a count of how many characters you're printing and have a loop that prints a character up to 10 times, in an outer loop that will loop `total/10` times.

The modulus operator is a bit cleaner in code, though. It calculates the remainder after dividing the operands. For instance, `4 % 2` will result in `0` (4 = 2 * 2 + **0**) while `5 % 2` will result in `1` (5 = 2 * 2 + **1**). In your example, you would want to check for `(i % 10 == 0)`.